# IOS App not redirecting when hit using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, redirect

I have created anchor

```
<a id="openapp" href="my_app_url">
```

link with my app URL and when a user clicks on that from ios phone any browser it opens the particular app page. but when I do the same using javascript like below its redirecting me to app store of my app. it's not opening the app page.

```
$("#openapp").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

The following functionality can be achieved using the concept of **Universal Linking**.

This link can be helpful
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links?language=objc